# How can i get all possible combinations of sets and subsets of a list that satisfy conditions with Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

For a list of elements for L = (A B C D), to generate all the combinations possible of elements that satisfy the  lexicographical order of elements  (A < B < C < D ...< Z), will be generated all combination.
For example L = (A B C D) well output (A),  (B),  (C),  (D),  (A B),  (B C),  (C D),  (A B C),  (B C D), (A B C D).

Comment: Do you mean that the elements in each subset are ordered, or that you're getting the subsets in order, or both? Your example shows both, but I'm not sure if it's what your question is asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) (not lexicological) order can be obtained through the following function that checks if the list `a` precedes the list `b` in lexicographical order:

```
(defun lex<= (a b)
  (or (null a)
      (and b 
           (string<= (car a) (car b))
           (lex<= (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
```

so, you could produce all the combinations, like in the answer of coredump, and then sort them with `(sort result #'lex<=)`.

Comment: `(sort (powerset '(a b c d)) #'lex<=)` or, if you want to eliminate `nil` from the result, `(sort (remove nil (powerset '(a b c d))) #'lex<=)`, with `powerset` defined as in the answer of coredump.

Comment: If I read this correctly, then sorting will put `nil` values to the beginning of the sorted range. Removing them after sorting is then obviously the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just write simple function to get power set of your list, and then just remove an empty set, and order it in any way you want.

```
(defun powerset (lst)
  (if lst (mapcan (lambda (el) (list (cons (car lst) el) el))
                (powerset (cdr lst)))
      '(())))

CL-USER> (powerset '(A B C D))
((A B C D) (B C D) (A C D) (C D) (A B D) (B D) (A D) (D) (A B C) (B C) (A C)
 (C) (A B) (B) (A) NIL)
```

To get exactly your describet output you can remove NIL and reverse it:

```
CL-USER> (reverse (remove nil (powerset '(A B C D))))
((A) (B) (A B) (C) (A C) (B C) (A B C) (D) (A D) (B D) (A B D) (C D) (A C D)
 (B C D) (A B C D))
```

Is this what you want?

UPDATE. Sorry, didn't mention that you want it sorte in another way. You should resort it:

```
CL-USER> (sort 
           (reverse
             (remove nil
                     (powerset '(A B C D))))
             #'< :key #'length)
((A) (B) (C) (D) (A B) (A C) (B C) (A D) (B D) (C D) (A B C) (A B D) (A C D)
 (B C D) (A B C D))
```

And this is another, more imparative solution, using `loop` macro, doing what you described:

```
(defun combinations (lst)
  (loop :for i :below (expt 2 (length lst))
        :when (loop :for j :below i :for el :in lst if (logbitp j i) :collect el)
        :collect it :into result
        :finally (return (sort result #'< :key #'length))))

CL-USER> (combinations '(A B C D E)) 
((A) (B) (C) (D) (E) (A B) (A C) (B C) (A D) (B D) (C D) (A E) (B E) (C E)
 (D E) (A B C) (A B D) (A C D) (B C D) (A B E) (A C E) (B C E) (A D E) (B D E)
 (C D E) (A B C D) (A B C E) (A B D E) (A C D E) (B C D E) (A B C D E))
```

Comment: unfortunately, there are some combination that didn't satisfy the  (A < B < C < D ...< Z)(<-lexicological order) for example (A C) (A D) (B D) (A B D) (A C D)..  output for CL-USER> (combinations '(A B C D E))  need to look like  (A) (A B) (A B C) (A B C D) (A B C D E) (B) (B C) (B C D) (B C D E) (C) (C D) (C D E) (D) (D E) (E)  they go after lexicological order A < B < C < D ...< Z)